# Twig stylesheets inheritance problem - Symfony 4

Tags: html, symfony, twig

As I am working with Symfony 4 and Twig I made a kind of structure to extend templates and include some parts.

I want a frontend and backend page for my project.

Structure:

[image: Filestructure]

I included the `base/head.html.twig` inside the `base.html.twig`:

[image: base.twig]

The `base/head.html.twig` this template contains the following:

[image: head.twig]

And now I would like to get a stylesheet specially for the backend:

[image]

And this is where the problem is. Because it won't get inherited by the `base/head.html.twig`.

I have searched the internet for it and tried several things. Maybe you know the answer?

Comment: My proxy prevents me to see the pictures. Is there a way you can post that in a different way?

Comment: For this prupose you have to use `embed` instead of `include` (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html), but I would recomment you to copy the content from `base/head.html.twig` directly to `base.html.twig`. From my point of view this more clear to have all in one base tempalte

Comment: @Fabian - Not sure how an embed would solve this issue?

Comment: @DarkBee _"It allows you to include another template's contents, just like include does. But it also allows you to override any block defined inside the included template, like when extending a template"_ this what the author is trying to achieve, if I undstood the question correctly.

Comment: Not quite - That mean the embed would be in every template and not inside `base.html`

Comment: Thats the reason why I recomment to copy the content in the `base.html` directly. That would be the simplest and cleanest solution.

Comment: U did not point out in your comment, that the embed would be in every template that extends `base.twig`, that is what i'm trying to point out

Comment: @Viperium - Please don't post code as an image though

Comment: @DarkBee Sorry, what would have been a better way to post the code?

Comment: @Fabian I tested it with embed but didnt got it to work.

Comment: @Viperium, just post the code in the editor and mark it as code with the `{}` button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use horizontal [reuse](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html) for this I guess. The setup u'd use should be something like this,

*head.twig*

```
{% block head %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" />
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
{% endblock %}
```

*base.twig*

```
{% use 'head.twig' %}

{% block content %} {% endblock %}
```

*actual_template.twig*

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block title %}My title{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bar.css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block('head') }} {# inject head.twig in content #}
{% endblock %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/czb6e2)

Comment: In any case better than embed :)

Comment: Yes and no, the 2nd part u've suggested is even better. Just put the head part in the full base

Comment: I tried this out. And it does work as aspected. Only I used it in `base.html.twig` with the following: `{% use 'base/head.html.twig' %}` and below it `{{ block('head') }}`